# How to assign date value to all returned mysql queries

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose I have a table as such:

```
ID  |  Date      |  Owner   |  Activity
----------------------------------------
 1  |  1/2/2011  |  Joe     |  Login
 2  |  2/1/2011  |  Mary    |  Logout
 1  |  2/3/2011  |  Bob     |  Process
 3  |  5/6/2010  |  Harry   |  Send
 2  |  8/1/2011  |  Alice   |  Hide
```

How can I run a query that retrieves all values but for the date field I have the max(date) for that id for EACH entry.

Thus if I were to select * (with other statements I don't yet know how to run) the output would be:

```
ID  |  Date      |  Owner   |  Activity
----------------------------------------
 1  |  2/3/2011  |  Joe     |  Login
 2  |  8/1/2011  |  Mary    |  Logout
 1  |  2/3/2011  |  Bob     |  Process
 3  |  5/6/2010  |  Harry   |  Send
 2  |  8/1/2011  |  Alice   |  Hide
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` on a subquery grouping by ID to return the `MAX(Date)` should do the job:

```
SELECT 
  t.ID,
  d.maxdate
  t.Owner,
  t.Activity
FROM 
  tbl t INNER JOIN (
   SELECT ID, MAX(Date) AS maxdate FROM tbl GROUP BY ID
  ) d ON t.ID = d.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION` out of Oracle's analytic functions might be another way for doing what you are looking for. I never actually used it and I have absolutely no Idea, whether the Non-Oracle-World also has something like this, but maybe you want to take a look at it:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions001.htm#i1000371
- http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html
- http://orafaq.com/node/55
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Analytical-functions/PARTITIONBYdividethegroupsintosubgroups.htm

Good Luck!

edit: but if possible and if it gives you the correct result, I would go with Michael's Answer.