# How to get maxdate for all like entries MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I asked this question and got a great answer for mysql:  [How to assign date value to all returned mysql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9068231/968233)  but now I need to do the same in MS SQL (SQL Server 2005).  Caveat is that I have a case statement that seems to be breaking things.  I have two queries as such:

```
select * from (select row_number()
  over (order by a.device ASC)
  AS rownum, a.device, staff, requestDate, m.maxDate, attribute = 
                 REPLACE((SELECT attribute AS [data()]
                 FROM deviceList
                 WHERE device = a.device
                 ORDER BY device FOR xml PATH('')), ' ',  ' ')
  FROM deviceList a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT device, MAX(requestDate) AS maxDate
                 FROM ASSIGNMENT GROUP BY device) m on m.device = a.device
  RIGHT JOIN Assignment
      ON (Assignment.device=a.device)
  GROUP BY a.device, staff, maxDate, requestDate, contract)
  AS B WHERE B.rownum > 0;





select * from (select row_number()
  over (order by a.device ASC)
  AS rownum, a.device, staff, requestDate, CONVERT(
    varchar, dateadd(year,
    (CASE
        WHEN contract = '10' THEN 1
        WHEN contract = '20' THEN 2
        WHEN contract = '30' THEN 3
        ELSE 3
        END), m.maxDate) 107) as myEndDate, attribute = 
                 REPLACE((SELECT attribute AS [data()]
                 FROM deviceList
                 WHERE device = a.device
                 ORDER BY device FOR xml PATH('')), ' ',  ' ')
  FROM deviceList a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT device, MAX(requestDate) AS maxDate
                 FROM ASSIGNMENT GROUP BY device) m on m.device = a.device
  RIGHT JOIN Assignment
      ON (Assignment.device=a.device)
  GROUP BY a.device, staff, myEndDate, requestDate, contract)
  AS B WHERE B.rownum > 0;
```

The first statement works great, like entries (those with same 'device' label) have the correct endDate.  However when I try to increment the date according to the case statement things go awry.  Date are incremented but not the same.  Why would the case statement break things of this nature?

UPDATE:
If I have two values of dates for one device as such:

```
2/1/2010
1/1/2010
```

with contract = 10

after the query the respective dates are:

```
2/1/2011
2/1/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the whole `CASE` statement in the `GROUP BY` clause.  SQL Server doesn't necessarily process the `SELECT` elements before the `GROUP BY` is performed, so aliases defined there can't be used.  ([Longer explanation here](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-use-a-select-list-alias-in-the-where-or-group-by-clause.html)).

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
  OVER (ORDER BY a.device ASC)
  AS rownum, a.device, staff, requestDate, CONVERT(
    varchar, dateadd(year,
    (CASE
        WHEN contract = '10' THEN 1
        WHEN contract = '20' THEN 2
        WHEN contract = '30' THEN 3
        ELSE 3
        END), m.maxDate) 107) as myEndDate, attribute = 
                 REPLACE((SELECT attribute AS [data()]
                 FROM deviceList
                 WHERE device = a.device
                 ORDER BY device FOR xml PATH('')), ' ',  ' ')
  FROM deviceList a
  INNER JOIN (SELECT device, MAX(requestDate) AS maxDate
                 FROM ASSIGNMENT GROUP BY device) m on m.device = a.device
  RIGHT JOIN Assignment
      ON (Assignment.device=a.device)
  GROUP BY a.device, staff, CONVERT(
    varchar, dateadd(year,
    (CASE
        WHEN contract = '10' THEN 1
        WHEN contract = '20' THEN 2
        WHEN contract = '30' THEN 3
        ELSE 3
        END), m.maxDate) 107), requestDate, contract)
  AS B WHERE B.rownum > 0;
```

Comment: That did not work.  It did not give an error but I still get the same result.  Just curious, did you try it on one of your databases to verify?  Don't see what I could have done wrong, hence my question.